# Enabling country/State picklist on custom fields in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Under Accounts, we have a custom fields for Project country and Project State, I am trying to enable to the Country/State picklist for these custom fields.

**Looking for any 3rd party plugin which will implement for Country/State picklist within Salesforce on custom field.**

Followed the steps from https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf for Enabling the State/country picklist, however it just worked on Address Standard field.

I need to implement the same on custom fields.

Please note: I have already implemented Global value picklist, and using the field dependency created controlling picklist (Country) and Controlled (State), however the dependent picklist has a limitation of 1500 values only.

Looking for any 3rd party plugin which will implement for Country/State picklist within Salesforce on custom field.

Answer (score 0):

According to me there is no standard approach or configuration you can do to achieve this. I would suggest you to have a custom metadata and lightning component.

On the Account have a text field:
1. Country
2. State

Custom Metadata:
1. Country
2. State

You can have a relationship field from State to Country. Create all the country and State records.

Build a custom lightning component to add it on the detail page of Account. On this component show the Country and State value from Account fields. Have a edit button when you edit Country and State should be displayed as picklist. When you change the Country State picklist should be populated from the metadata.